# How can I call a method on the current object to another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I call the Zamkniecie() file Window1.cs not the new object as I showed in the method Window_Closed(), but the object you are currently working with a file MainWindow.cs? 
Components of methods Zamkniecie() have been created in the file MainWindow.xaml

```
    File: Window1.cs 
    namespace AllSportsBets102
    {    
        public partial class Window1 : Window
        {
            public Window1(DataGrid zdg, List<Data2> dsx)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
                mw.Zamkniecie();
            }
        }
    }

    File: MainWindow.cs
    namespace AllSportsBets102
    {
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
              public MainWindow()
              {
                  InitializeComponent();
              }
              public void Zamkniecie()
              {
                    InfoStackPanel.IsEnabled = true;
                    KuponStackPanel1.IsEnabled = true;
                    KuponStackPanel2.IsEnabled = true;
                    FiltrStackPanel.IsEnabled = true;
                    WszystkieZdarzeniaStackPanel1.IsEnabled = true;
                    WszystkieZdarzeniaStackPanel2.IsEnabled = true;
                    KuponLabel.IsEnabled = true;
                    WszystkieLabel.IsEnabled = true;
                    InfoLabel.IsEnabled = true;
                    StackPanel1Copy.IsEnabled = true;
                    StackPanel2Copy.IsEnabled = true;  
               }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options:

1. Give Window1 a reference to MainWindow so it can call the Zamkniecie method.
2. Make the Zamkniecie method static.
3. Move the Zamkniecie method into Window1.
4. If there is only one instance of MainWindow, implement MainWindow as a singleton so you will have access to it from anywhere.
5. If MainWindow instantiates Window1, raise an event from Window1 that is handled on MainWindow.
6. If MainWindow does not instantiate Window1, implement the observer pattern.

I prefer option 5, if it's possible because it more closely allow each class to manage itself. If you only want to call Zamkniecie when Window1 closes, you should be able to recognize that from MainWindow. Here's a code snippet that would go in MainWindow:

```
Window1 window1 = new Window1();
window1.ShowDialog();
Zamkniecie();
```

Note: Which file these classes are in makes no difference as long as they are in the same namespace.

Comment: 1. I would have to have the only class without a xaml file, because the components are not visible.                                    2. Static method requires static fields                            3. Move method causes error in all fields ex : The name 'WszystkieZdarzeniaStackPanel2' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user231605 I'm not sure what you mean in 1. For 2, you could implement a MainWindow as a singleton first if there is really only one instance of a MainWindow in your app. I will update answer to reflect this.

Comment: ok, but when it calls the method on the static object is working in his fields that are initialized when creating the object.

Comment: I added a few more options. Take a look at 5. It circumvents all this.

Comment: I chose option 5 and I don't know how to do it. Could you write me a sample code or more explain ?

Comment: Is MainWindow the only place that calls Window1? Do you need to call Zamkniecie only on when Window1 closes? Is Window1 modal?

Comment: Yes MainWindow is only place  thet calls Window1. Yes I need call Zamkniecie only on when Window1 closes. What is the modal ?

Comment: Modal is when Window1 is the only window that can have focus. Is that what you have?

Comment: I have only 2 windows. First is a MainWindow and second Window1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46446/discussion-between-kevin-swarts-and-user231605)

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be redundant, but the quickest way would be to add an

```
 using MainWindow.cs;
```

at the top of the Window1.cs file

Comment: I can't add using MainWindow.cs; or using MainWindow.xaml.cs; 
at the top of the Window1.cs file, beacuse I have error: The type or namespace name 'MainWindow' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: using is for namespaces, not class names.

Comment: I have access to the MainWindow class, but it is about that I do not want to create a new object, because I have a different value components. The idea of calling a method without creating a new class MainWindow.